# The archive passed validation with several warning

Tags: ios, xcode

I am going to upload my first app to iTuneCnnect but validation completed with 
several warnings. I don't know how that can be fixed.
The message show like this

**The archive passed validation with sevral warnigs**

**iTune store operation failed:null**

And they have sent me an eamil also

"Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Sign & Fill". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team"

But I am using "Standard architecture and iOS 8 latest SDK".

can anybody help me?

Comment: Check both project settings and target settings. Target settings inherit from project settings but can override them.

Comment: What I have to check in them? In my case both are same

Comment: SDK has nothing to do with the build you are creating. What are your valid architectures in the build settings?

Comment: Valid architechture are : arm64 armv7 armv7s

Comment: Just select them in Xcode and press backspace to reset them to default value.

Comment: @Adam: tried. but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Remove armv7s, to build universal binary with latest XCode you need arm64 and armv7  [image: setting working]